# WARNING: Unable to find module repositories. "Get-PSRepository" ubuntu20.04

Tags: repository, powershell

I was trying to install Az-Module in my Ubuntu power-shell, But It wasn't installing than I double checked the PSRepository and I came to know that I don't have any repository there.

I also have tried to Register the default repository But it didn't worked out and Also, I've tried to uninstall power shell and re-install it but nope, Nothing is working out.

Need expert advise on it how to Register PSREPOSITORY successfully and Install Az module.

The main point is: I do not have any gallery in my power-shell. Also, I have tried this command to Register the repository. Here's the command I'm using to register the default repository: "register-psrepository psgallery default". But after getting the PsRepository again, It did not show any Repository.

Comment: What is the exact command and any errors you get when you try to install this app?

Comment: The main point is: I do not have any gallery in my power-shell. Also, I have tried this command to Register the repository.  Here's the command I'm using to register the default repository:  "register-psrepository psgallery default".  But after getting the PsRepository again, It didnt show any Repository.

Comment: I moved this comment to the question. Info for the question needs to be in the question not as a comment. You can use the edit command to do this.